# Clarification on "usage" of realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

May I clarify that the number of connection showing at each point is the maximum number of simutaneous connection reached during that particular hour? or it means the total number of connections made during that particular hour? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage stats indeed show the maximum number of users that were connected at any one time during that hour.

It is not the total number of users that connected during that hour. If you want to know that, you can easily build it by having each user write an event to the database when it connects or by using a product like Firebase Analytics.